# How to extract user IDs from URLs inside Pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract

Data frame has 1,050,000 rows.

Input: (a pandas dataframe column)

```
UserImage
    https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a/AItbvmkI4RoZOTFftgRqwJ0QVl-OqLw0PXFRQsQmzPwayQ=mo
    https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/EGemoI2NTXmTsBVtJqk8jxF9rh8ApRWfsIMQSt2uE4OcpQqbFu7f7NbTK05lx80nuSijCz7sc3a277R67g
    https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a-/AFdZucpr-V6JJAWHdTjxYVPa15fmQC7pWl5Xd5StFt1E'
```

Output:

```
UserIDs
AItbvmkI4RoZOTFftgRqwJ0QVl-OqLw0PXFRQsQmzPwayQ
EGemoI2NTXmTsBVtJqk8jxF9rh8ApRWfsIMQSt2uE4OcpQqbFu7f7NbTK05lx80nuSijCz7sc3a277R67g
AFdZucpr-V6JJAWHdTjxYVPa15fmQC7pWl5Xd5StFt1E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a perfect use case for a regex:

```
df['UserIDs'] = df['UserImage'].str.extract('^.*/([^/=]+)[^/]*$')
```

Or if you want to keep only alphanum + `-`:

```
df['UserIDs'] = df['UserImage'].str.extract('^.*/([-\w]+)[^/]*$')
```

output:

```
                                           UserImage  \
0  https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a/AItbvm...   
1  https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/EGemoI2N...   
2  https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a-/AFdZu...   

                                             UserIDs  
0     AItbvmkI4RoZOTFftgRqwJ0QVl-OqLw0PXFRQsQmzPwayQ  
1  EGemoI2NTXmTsBVtJqk8jxF9rh8ApRWfsIMQSt2uE4OcpQ...  
2       AFdZucpr-V6JJAWHdTjxYVPa15fmQC7pWl5Xd5StFt1E
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/74mZ5H/1)

Comment: The [python regex documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use:

```
df['UserImage'] = df['UserImage'].str.split('/').str[-1].str.split('=').str[0]
print (df)
                                           UserImage
0     AItbvmkI4RoZOTFftgRqwJ0QVl-OqLw0PXFRQsQmzPwayQ
1  EGemoI2NTXmTsBVtJqk8jxF9rh8ApRWfsIMQSt2uE4OcpQ...
```